# Scope of inner beans

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am new to Spring’s framework. I came across inner beans concept and want to know what will be scope of inner beans. Can anyone explain me what will be inner beans scope, will it depend on the bean in which it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inner-beans) states

> An inner bean definition does not require a defined id or name; the
>   container ignores these values. **It also ignores the scope flag**. Inner
>   beans are always anonymous and they are always created with the outer
>   bean. It is not possible to inject inner beans into collaborating
>   beans other than into the enclosing bean.

So an inner bean has no scope and basically can't be used by anything other than the enclosing bean.

Answer (score 2):

Some important points about inner beans:

- Inner beans are always anonymous and they are always scoped as prototypes.
- You can't inject inner beans into other beans other than the enclosing bean.
- When a bean needs to be used for only one purpose. it’s advised to declare 
    it as an inner bean

Answer (score 1):

Inner beans  are implicitly made anonymous but also scoped prototype, which makes sense since they won’t be reused anywhere else.